Bootable USB not detected in BIOS menu
This is honestly embarrassing for me. I'm currently trying to switch from NixOS back to Void Linux after trying the distribution for a few months now. I got the Void .iso file, created a bootable USB drive with the dd command on a freshly bought 16GB Sandisk drive. The laptop itself is a Dell Latitude 7310.
Problem is, the BIOS doesn't detect the USB drive at all. Safe mode is already disabled and the only option that I'm presented with in the BIOS setup is to add manually the USD drive myself - BIOS list options.
It's strange because this is the first time happening on this particular laptop. I've installed Void, Guix and even FreeBSD on this one before and never had this issue. Anyone got any tips?
The drive itself was formatted with mkfs.vfat before dd was used for the .iso file, in case that's helpful.

No, formatting before dd is unhelpful and a waste of time. Whatever filesystem was there no longer is, having been replaced by the ISO's filesystem.

click add boot option button.

Never mind, the problem was solved after using a different app (balenaEtcher) to create a bootable USB drive.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

This is self answered...

@help-info.de How is answering my own question a problem?

@Destroy666 Well unfortunately, all that I did was to use a different command line utility to burn the ISO image, rebooted the laptop and now the USB drive was visible.

@Thomas Petit - excuse me, no problem. My comment was more review comment related.   It was apparently not recognized that you gave the answer yourself.

@help-info.de Ah, apologies in that case as well

@help-info.de it was noticed. As someone with 2k+ rep you should know this is far from optimal quality and at most a comment...  Thomas Petit what's a "different app"? Do you think this answer wouldbe helpful to you if you Googled a problem and read it?
"
